# Choosing selected section from an SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I have a database in which I have a column in which each row contains either "true" or "false". Is it possible for a cursor to only select the rows which have the value "true" in that column. How would you write the database query to get that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT your_column, other_col
FROM your_table
WHERE your_column = ?
```

Can be used with a [`rawQuery()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29), which will replace the `?` with your value to prevent you from SQL-injections.

Comment: Will this return all of the other columns also? Is that what you mean by "other_col"

Comment: No, this will only return the columns that you specify. If you only need the `your_column`, just leave the `other_col` out. If you need more columns, you can add them to the result by adding their names (delimited by a `,`) to the `SELECT`-statement.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Appreciate it.